# TSQL Replace rule for: a|2$5.0| to a|5.0|5.0|

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with string field like a|2$5.0| and I need to convert it to the following one a|5.0|5.0|.

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

The logic is as follows:

- a - is the first character od each string
- | - is a list elements separator
- $ - if there is a $ sign in string, the element (value between $ and | signs) should be repeated as many times as the value of number preceeding $ sign (in my example 2 times).

String can be also more complex, but the same logic applies, eg.:

```
a|2$5.0|3.1|-4.2|3$-9.6|
```

which should be converted to:

```
a|5.0|5.0|3.1|-4.2|-9.6|-9.6|-9.6|
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I highly recommend fixing your design here.

Comment: Fix your design. Storing multiple values in a field violates the most basic database design rule. Those values can't be queried or indexed, as you found out. The solution is to use proper tables, rows and fields

Comment: The problem is that it is 3rd party solution and I have no influence on this table design. The reason of my question is that I try to convert this table to more db friendly format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, like the comment say, I recommend fixing the design. Storing delimited data in your database is a bad idea, if I am honest. T-SQL is also a poor choice here, as it's far from good at string manipulation.

That being said, you *can* do this. I use [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) here, as it is ordinal position aware. if you're not on a recent version of SQL Server, you'll need to replace `STRING_AGG` with the old `FOR XML PATH` method:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(NS.NewString,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber,T.I) + '|' AS NewString
FROM (VALUES('a|2$5.0|3.1|-4.2|3$-9.6|'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.YourString,'|') DS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('$',DS.Item)))CI(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(LEFT(DS.Item,NULLIF(CI.I,0)-1),1)))R(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(DS.Item,1,CI.I,'')))NS(NewString)
     JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))T(I) ON R.I >= T.I;
```

Comment: Larnu, thank you for your answer. It helped me to fix the table format so it's more db friendly now.